# Component name different to the default view name, how to display default view?

Tags: component, development, view

My component is named "com_xsomething" (to make it distinct).

My main view is called "Something".

I want to name my view "Something" rather than "xSomething".

How do I write the main controller's `display()` function to display the "Something" View and not have Joomla look for "xSomething"?

I tried the below code but it failed miserably:

```
class xSomethingController extends JControllerLegacy{
    function display(){
        $viewsomething = $this->getView('Something');
        $viewsomething->display();
    }
}
```

Error:

> 500 View not found [name, type, prefix]: something, , xsomethingView

I can't name my view "xSomething" because it doesn't make sense in the context my component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question upon reviewing the API documentation and playing around with the code.

I was able to display a different view by specifying the view type and view class prefixes:

```
class xSomethingController extends JControllerLegacy{
    function display(){
        $viewsomething = $this->getView('Something', 'html', 'xSomethingView');
        $viewsomething->display();
    }
}
```